# Do full-stack JavaScript frameworks create the HTML on the client or server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, meteor

According to [this article](http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-JavaScript-future-web-apps/) from AirBnB

it says

> A Hybrid Approach
>
> At the end of the day, we really want a hybrid of the new and old
>   approaches: we want to serve fully-formed HTML from the server for
>   performance and SEO, but we want the speed and flexibility of
>   client-side application logic.
>
> To this end, we’ve been experimenting at Airbnb with “Isomorphic
>   JavaScript” apps, which are JavaScript applications that can run both
>   on the client-side and the server-side.

So, I am a bit confused as to whether full-stack JavaScript frameworks render HTML files on the server or on the client. My most current educated guess is that some frameworks create HTML files exclusively on the client, some exclusively on the server and some are mixed. But which are which?

Comment: Maybe useful information to you : http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, it can get a little confusing. Especially if you just read about it and don't actually try it out.

I try to clarify it very quickly but if anything is unclear let me know :)

First thing first: What is Isomorphic JavaScript? Simplified it means that you use the very same code on front-end and back-end which is usually possible thanks Node.js (or the new fork iojs).

Now, until recently it was normal to deliver a more or less static html page to the client. Doesn't matter if the html is actually static on the server or the server creates it dynamically - the client just renders the HTML it gets.

With the new frameworks like Angular or React the approach is differently: You basically create the HTML dynamically on the client side and ask the server just for data. This means your server is in general just an (json) API!

However, some of the frameworks have an option to "pre-render" the html serverside which basically just means the initial request returns the proper html as we know it already and from there the clients takes over to manipulate the DOM again.

Usually you do that because you want a "single-page" Application that has more than one page. Single-Page just means you don't need to reload.
And the main reason you want that is because your webapp looks nicer on smartphones/tablets.
The aim is to get a "native" feeling even though it's "just" a website.

It has a few more advantages and obviously also quite a few disadvantages but if you're interested in them try to learn one of those frameworks and take it from there.
Angular.js is currently the "standard" framework that most people use - so can't really go wrong there.

I personally like React.js quite a bit but it's not as popular as Angular (yet?).

Some people even combine the two of them but you really need to know what you do to make that work in a way that makes sense so just go with one ->they both provide everything you need.

You can also have a look at Ember or Backbone but the concept is pretty similar to Angular and probably a little less complex but not as widely used.

Hope it's a little clearer now and I didn't make it even worse :)

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you are affirming what I implied with my question. Can you clarify your response a little bit, as to which frameworks have which options in terms of HTML render server/client side? You should read the article I posted originally if you haven't already !

Comment: They usual all render client side because if you do it serverside you can fallback to a classic approach.
However, react def has an optional serverside pre-render option (Isomorphic - so you use the same code server/client side).
There is most likely some module that provides the same for Angular or similar frameworks but afaik it doesn't come with it out of the box...

Comment: The AirBnB article seems to insinuate that Meteor is one of the few isomorphic frameworks that is doing the "hybrid approach" that the article refers to.

Comment: Possible but I never used it so I can't tell you much about it, sorry.